# What is event logging? and how do I write an event log file?

Tags: file, visual-c++, event-log

What is event logging? and how do I write an event log file for an application? I want to log all the activities of the application including when it uses a .dll, etc. and also show information of the application.

Comment: write to an event log file is what you mean?

Answer (score 5):

There is a good article on CodeProject.com that should give you the information you need to understand and use the Windows event log.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/xeventlog.aspx

If you don't want to use the Windows event log and log to a text file, etc then take a look at [Pantheios](http://www.pantheios.org/).

Comment: +1 for the link.  Looks like this project provides a DLL that very nicely wraps the nasty looking Windows Event Log API.

Answer (score 3):

As you write to an event log file, if *the file is not created then it will be created* [write to an event log](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815661)

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385780(VS.85).aspx) and for cpp source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382690(VS.85).aspx

Comment: nice.  a downvote with no comment.  the link is useful - not sure why a downvote was necessary unless I have a stalker.