# What is Windows Event Logging

Tags: windows, event-log

Can anyone explain what is Windows Event Logging?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/?Query=Windows+Event+Logging

Answer (score 3):

Try this related stack overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655592/what-is-event-logging-and-how-do-i-write-an-event-log-file).

Answer (score 1):

I think everything you need to know would be here:

[Event Logging (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363652(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When you send log messages to the Windows Event Logger. You can see the messages by going to the Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework I'm assuming you just want the basic idea of it. If your program encounters a serious error, you write it to the Windows event log so you can keep a record and look at it later to figure out what went wrong.  Look it up on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385780(VS.85).aspx) or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer#Windows_Event_Log)

Answer (score 0):

Windows Event Log is a component of Microsoft's Windows NT line of operating systems that lets administrators and users view the event logs on a local or remote machine.
Windows Event Logging is the process of writing applications' events into that centrolized log storage.